# Disable wifi adapter warning

Tags: windows-7, notifications, wireless-adapter

I normally have my WIFI adapter disabled in Windows 7.

Whenever I restart or boot the machine, it pops up a warning that it is disabled. Doh, I know this. The balloon notification appears in the bottom right of the screen:

[image: wifi balloon notification]

How can I disable this annoying warning (which interrupts and delays the startup process btw)?

Note that this is a "balloon warning" from the righthand side of the taskbar (where utilities/hardware are located). The activating software is the "Intel PROSet Wireless WiFi Software".

Here is the "Customize" options from Windows with the Wireless item among them. Note that there is no "Show Icon and Hide Notifications" choice:

[image: Taskbar Items]

Comment: Is this a windows warning or it has something to do with your laptop/motherboard manufacturer? If the latter, there is typically a setting in their "Connection Manager".

Comment: I've not seen Windows do this, I'm guessing (as Mahdi suggests) that it's a "feature" of your Wifi adapter's software. Can you provide a screenshot of the message you're getting? It may help identify where it's coming from and how to stop it. Also, please edit your question to include the make/model of your WiFi adapter, and if your machine is an OEM PC/notebook please include the make and model # of that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem. The key is to single click on the notification balloon. You have to do this fast, because it disappears after a few seconds. When you do this the following "troubleshooter" pops up:

[image: Intel wireless troubleshooter]

Notice how there is a blue "Disable notifications" label in the lower left. This is actually a toggle believe it or not. Click it once to disable notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who has posted previously. None of the advice worked for me exactly, but there were enough clues and suggestions to point me in the right direction:

1) Clicking the "disable notifications" link on the Intel Wireless Troubleshooter screen only works for connection *errors* and not for normal connection behavior. For me, the annoying messages are the ones like "you are now connected to xxxx network". the Disable Notification link doesn't affect these messages because they are not errors; they are merely "helpful" information.

2) The Windows taskbar icon controls didn't work for me because my messages were not from Windows but rather from the Intel connection utility.

3) To turn off the Intel messages, I had to left click on the Intel wireless icon in the taskbar (not the Windows network icon but the Intel one), then select "Use Windows to manage wifi." This means that the Intel utility is no longer involved, and the Windows taskbar icon controls should now work. In my case, I hide the Intel icon and notifications but I show the Windows network icon and notifications. This makes the network icon always visible, but there are never any notification, so I don't have to deal with that annoyance. When I'm on wifi, the network icon looks like wifi signal bars, and a simple glance at the icon tells me whether I'm connected and how strong the signal is. If I want more detail, a single click on the network icon shows connection status, available networks, etc.

Summary:
1) Set Intel ProSet taskbar icon to "Use Windows to manage wifi";
2) Set Windows "network" taskbar icon to show icon & notifications

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To disable notification about the wireless connection at the start-up,Please follow the below steps

(i) Open the Run using ctrl + R and type regedit.

(ii) Navigate to the following subkey:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Curre ntVersion\Explorer\Advanced

(iii) Right click and create a  new DWORD and name it EnableBalloonTips.

(iv) Click on it and select the value as 0 for hexadecimal.

Now log off the windows and check whether you are notified at the restart.

Comment: That would probably work, but it disables all balloon notifications. Is there a way to disable just the one from the WIFI adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in functions provided by Windows for task notifications.

1. Click on the notification button and choose `Customize...`.
2. Find the notification you are looking for.
3. Change the `Behaviors` to `Hide icon and notifications`.
4. Click OK to save.

[image]

Comment: Right, the only problem is that if possible I would like to show the icon because when I do have the adapter turned on, I want to check its status quickly. Unfortunately, there is no "Show Icon and Hide Notifications" option.

Comment: Then turn it back on. Sometimes you can't have everything. :-)